# Is there a way to chain an assertion in testcafe?

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, assertion, web-testing, testcafe

I have a scenario where depending on a previous condition, the result could be 'this' OR 'that'.

For example, how would I write the expectation if I want the .contains assertion to look for `foo` OR `bar`?

```
await t.expect('foo bar').contains('bar')
```

Comment: You can use your `await t.expect('foo bar').contains('bar')` code to check the 'contains' condition for strings. 
If you want to check the 'contains' condition for other data types (DOM nodes, for example), then it's better to choose a different way. 
Could you please provide more details about your scenario?

Comment: I have a scenario, where when the user clicks on the Submit button, the result could be "A" or "B".

Comment: You can use RegExp in assertions
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#match

`await t.expect('foo').match(/foo|bar/);`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
if (await Selector('div').withText('testee@tester.com').exists)
    {
        console.log("PASS")
    }
else if (await Selector('div').withText('testeetwo@tester.com').exists)
    {
        console.log("PASS")
    }
else
    {
        console.log("FAIL")
    }
```